# Use python function arg as a default argument too

Tags: python

I want to write a function that has a default value that is another input of the function.  I'd like something like this:

```
def pythag_thm(a, b=a):
    return (a**2 + b**2)**.5
```

but I get a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. I realize I could do something like:

```
def pythag_thm(a, b=False):
     if b==False:
         return (a**2 + a**2)**.5
     else:
         return (a**2 + b**2)**.5
```

but this does not seem very 'pythonic'. Is there a clean way to do this? Am I just thinking of this in the wrong way?

Comment: careful, if b is 0, then since 0==False, you'll get a surprise bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What people usually do is

```
def pythag_thm(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a

    return (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** .5
```

Answer (score 2):

default arguments are evaluated at the time of the function definition, so there is no way to do it that way.

```
import math
def pythag_thm(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
    return math.hypot(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. People usually use `None` for this:

   ```
   def pythag_thm(a, b=None):
       b = b if b is not None else a
       ...
   ```
2. If `None` is a valid value for your `b` you can create your own `DEFAULT` value:

   ```
   DEFAULT = object()

   def pythag_thm(a, b=DEFAULT):
       b = b if b is not DEFAULT else a
       ...
   ```
3. If you are in the mood you can also handle the `*args` and `**kwargs` yourself:

   ```
   def pythag_thm(a, *args, **kwargs):
       try
           b = args[0]
           assert len(args) == 1
       except IndexError:
           try:
               b = kwargs.pop('b')
               assert not kwargs
           except KeyError:
               b = a
       ...
   ```

You probably want to stick with variant 1 or 2 as it is most pythonic and does not require you to fiddle with `args` and `kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no scope in the input for b to know what a is. They don't exist until they're in the body of the function

The most pythonic way I can think of is:

```
def example(a, b=None):
    if not b: b = a
    // code here
```

EDIT: identical to @pavel's answer - got to learn faster typing.  For lurkers: there's a behavior difference. Pavel's answer is better, mine  wont' correctly handle something like:

```
example (2, 0)
```

because the b is None test is the more correct one

Comment: This is buggy: what if `b == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be extra careful when providing a default value, as an example when you want the default value to be a list, here is a mistake:

```
>>> def function_with_default(arg=[]):
...    return arg
...
```

here is an example that has unexpected results:

```
>>> ret = function_with_default()
>>> ret
[]
>>> ret.append(2)
>>> # unexpected side-effects ...
>>> ret2 = function_with_default()
>>> ret2
[2]
```

What happens in the example above is that you can actually modified the object.
Here is the way to do it without side-effects:

```
>>> def function_with_default(arg=None):
...    if arg is None:
...       arg = []
...    return arg
...
```

same example, different output:

```
>>> ret = function_with_default()
>>> ret
[]
>>> ret.append(2)
>>> # no unexpected side-effects this time ...
>>> ret2 = function_with_default()
>>> ret2
[]
```

to answer your question, you can use.

```
def pythag_thm(a, b=None):
   if b is None:
      b = a
   return (a**2 + b**2)**.5
```